# When should I add "to" before an infinitive in a parallelism sentence?

Tags: infinitives, parallelism, particles

Here is a sentence I wrote:

> All he can do, as it turns out, is to stay by her side, take her to wherever he goes and hope someday she will wake up.

I added **to** ahead of **take...** in the first place, but my foreign teacher told me there was no need to do that.

Here is another one:

> I won’t elaborate on his excellent judge of character or other things like willingness to take responsibility and **to** trust in his team here, determination and so on.

This time my teacher didn't tell me to delete the second **to**. I want to know if the second **to** is necessary? When should I keep the **to** ahead of the infinitive in a parallelism sentence and when not?

Comment: Either form would be alright in each of examples you quote. Whether you elide the parallel *to* is a matter of choice - you see it both ways. Including *to* adds a bit more emphasis to the point it introduces, but by and large the meaning is the same.

Comment: Thank you, WS2. also Thank @Andred Leach for correcting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Either form would be alright in each of examples you quote. Whether you elide the parallel *to* is a matter of choice - you see it both ways. Including *to* adds a bit more emphasis to the point it introduces, but by and large the meaning is the same

WS2 in a comment

Answer (score 2):

All he can ***do***, as it turns out, is to stay by her side, take her to wherever he goes and hope someday she will wake up.

When we have the verb 'do' in the subject, we normally omit 'to'.

Answer (score 2):

***All he can do, as it turns out, is to stay by her side, take her to wherever he goes and hope someday she will wake up.***

The above complex structure is a *coordinate structure*. When it come to the **full infinitive or the to- infinitive,** it has it rules that it follows together with Conjunctions.

Now, whenever there is a *conjunct* *"and"* used after a *to- infinitive verb*, the second verb does not take the **particle.... "to"**

```
 So one could say:
```

- All that he has to do, is **to stay** and **take her** to the hospital.

instead of

- All that he has to do, is **to stay** and **to take** her to the hospital. (*wrong*).

Moreover the sentence,
**I won’t elaborate on his excellent judge of character or other things like willingness to take responsibility and to trust in his team here, determination and so on** is wrong when it comes to the **full infinitive clause**

it is likewise the same as the former sentence. **to take responsibility** is ***to- infinitive or full infinitive***, and the second verb need not take a **particle "to"**.

Hence, the correct structure must be:

***I won’t elaborate on his excellent judge of character or other things like willingness to take responsibility and trust in his team here, determination and so on.***

*Research more on Non- finite Clause structures.*

Thank you.